# Javascript conflict with onclick and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, events

Hi and thanks for looking at my post.  I'm very new to scripting, and I'm having a simple problem that I can't figure out.  So...

I have a button that freezes up when I press it, and its "onclick" function doesn't get triggered.  There is a "onmouseout" function that is causing this, but I don't know why.

I'd like "onmouseout" and "onclick" functions to apply to one button, but it's not working.  Please see my code:

Javascript:

```
function popup() 
{
    alert("Hello World")
}

function pop2() 
{
    alert("Good job")
}

function pop3() 
{
    alert("CLICK ME!")
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Hello World">
<input type="button" onclick="pop2()" onmouseout="pop3()" value="click me">
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/238Nz/2 (Be careful testing, and fixed.)

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/2R3Z5/

Comment: Using `console.log` instead of `alert`: http://jsfiddle.net/238Nz/3/

Comment: @Musa - It freezes for several seconds on my Firefox using the *fixed* `alert`s version I posted. The first one I posted had the functions in an `onload`. `:s` And note it does not happen in Chrome.

Comment: @Mark your code definitely works.

Comment: The HTML comment wrapping the script body is not a problem either: http://jsfiddle.net/238Nz/5/

Comment: The slight delay could be explained by the usage of onX attributes forcing an `eval` (which _is_ slow) on each click, or it's the `alert` that's slow.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I believe, in *Firefox* but not *Chrome*, that `onmouseout`-triggered `alert` is blocking the `onclick`-triggered `alert` somewhat artificially. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjusting your code to isolate and provide detail to what's going on, I've prepared the following:

**http://jsfiddle.net/238Nz/8/**

---

> ## <sup><sub><sup><sub>**Skip below this part for the answer. This is intended for Mark.**</sub></sup></sub></sup>
>
> <sup>Let's ignore whether or not using `on*` attributes to add handlers is considered good or bad<sup>$</sup>. Also, let's use some logging to check the order. I am using `console.log()` to send messages to the browser's Javascript console. In Firefox, I use Firebug, and Chrome has a built-in console. In both, right-click on the page and `Inspect Element`, then choose the `Console` tab for these tests.</sup>
>
> <sup>One more thing: jsFiddle can be a little complicated to figure out at first. The Javascript in the bottom, left pane is actually put *within* the `head` block *above* the `input` (and `body` tag) within the source. Right-click and `View Source` on the bottom, right (`Result`) pane and you'll see what the browser is using. It's just like your own example HTML document, just reordered for jsFiddle. Try not to be confused by how that works, though.</sup>

---

The markup I am using to test your problem is the following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="doclick()" onmouseout="domouseout()" value="Click">
```

Notice I plainly label my functions and use descriptive error messages. This helps me keep track of what is going on by embedding that detail within the *code* and the *message log information*. Always try to be descriptive in your labels (`function`, `var`, log information, etc.), instead of doing things like `yay!` or `what happened`. It's simply too hard to follow once your scripts get to be longer and more complex.

Next, I used the following function to narrow down and consistently replicate the same action:

```
function popup(msg) {
    // Note, console.log is first here. This is so that the
    // alert does not "steal" focus before I get any result.
    console.log(msg);

    // Now, let's try the alert. Notice, the same msg is used.
    alert(msg);
}
```

This allows me to call both `console.log` *and* `alert` in a specific order, from both event handlers. Next, I establish my two event handler functions:

```
function doclick() {
    popup('onclick fired');
}

function domouseout() {
    popup('onmouseout fired');
}
```

See, all they do is call `popup()` with an *action-specific* log message about *what was supposed to happen*. Since `alert`s are designed to "focus" to the user and block interaction, which appears to be a possible cause of the "frozen" browser frame.

What I do next is try this in different browsers. *Always* try to replicate and test across different browsers<sup>#</sup>. In this case, I notice a big difference between two...

- **Chrome**: Does not block processing; both `alert`s fire, and the `onmouseout`-fired `alert` is not run through `console.log` until *after* I hit `Ok` on the `alert` **and** and I move the mouse pointer off of the `input` element. This, it seems, is the desired outcome. Right?
- **Firefox (17.0.1)**: Firefox does show the behavior you're describing. Note, when I click on the button, I get both `doclick` ***and*** `domouseout()` called *at the same time*. So Firefox is detecting the `onclick` as taking the mouse pointer away from the button, and you get the "freeze". If you watch the `console`, you'll see both `log`s fire immediately, and you seemingly get no `alert` to interact with (by clicking `Ok`).
- **IE (7-9, 9 Compatibility View)**: IE of course provides an interesting illustration. For instance, when I click the button in IE9, I see:

  [image: onmouseout alert is on top of onclick alert???]

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzj82.png

  Which of course *appears to be the same effect Firefox is having*... But for some reason with Firefox, the `onmouseout`-fired `alert` does not focus on top of the `onclick`-fired `alert`. IE 7-9 plus Compatibility View all exhibit this particular behavior, with slight variations.
- **Opera (12.02)**: Opera does not fire the `onmouseout`-fired `alert` or `console.log` message until *after* the `onclick`-fired `alert` and log message, ***and*** you move the mouse (assuming you've moved it off of the `input` button element after clicking it). This seems weird, but more palatable than the Firefox and IE behaviors. Maybe I'm mistaken, though.

So what's happening? I'm not quite sure, but I think that the `onmouseout` is blocking the `onclick`'s `alert` from focusing to the user. If you hit `[Enter]` while it's frozen, you get the `onclick` alert but no `onmouseout`. Chrome seems correct here; Firefox's "popunder" alert seems, well, sorta fishy.

In summary, at least the *behavior* of the two events in this case are not *only specific* to Firefox. What *seems* to be specific to Firefox (at least 17.0.1) is the fact the `onmouseout`-fired `alert` does not focus correctly, and the page "appears to freeze". This seems like a bug. I wonder if it's been reported?

---

> <sub><sup>**$**</sup></sub>
>   <sup><sub>It's not *usually* a good idea to use inline attribute event handlers like `<input onclick="doclick()"...>`, but let's ignore what's beside the point here. See MDN's [`DOM Event` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event), specifically the [HTML attribute section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event#HTML_attribute), and realize this is a bit trickier and detailed than is worth going into here.</sub></sup>
>
> <sub><sup>**#**</sup></sub>
>   <sup><sub>If you continue working with Javascript within the browser, you'll find out IE is... special. It has a special place in history, so weird or "abnormal" behavior is not unusual when checking your code with versions of IE. Personally, I suggest learning and working within Firefox or Chrome, and then checking in IE and other browsers that it works.</sub></sup>

Comment: This bug is still alive. In Chrome and Firefox. Or have someone a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
var clicked = false;
function popup() 
{
    alert("Hello World")
}

function pop2(ev) 
{
    alert("Good job");
    clicked=true;
}

function pop3() 
{
    if(clicked == false)
    {
        alert("CLICK ME!");
    }
    clicked=false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Hello World">
<input type="button" onclick="return pop2(event)" onmouseout="pop3()" value="click me">
```

​[link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLuuQ/5/)

Comment: In Firefox, this actually still does the same thing ("freezes" the page), it just literally blocks the `onmouseout`-fired `alert` from being run. You can see what [IE 9 does in this screenshot](http://imgur.com/FkmD8), which is what Firefox appears to attempt to do (`onmouseout`-fired `alert` over the `onclick`-fired `alert`), but seems to screw up (bug?). See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since the click and mouseout/mouseleave events occur soon after the other on FireFox due to poor focusing during click event, we can add a sort of a delay for the code that will be processed during mouseout/mouseleave event. The following worked for me:

```
//Bind the element with classname to a function on click event
$(".rej").bind("click", showData);
//Bind the same element with classname to another function on mouseout event.
$(".rej").bind("mouseout", hideData);
```

Then you can proceed with your showData function. However in hideData function you will need to add a delay of few seconds before processing the code in that function, as show below:

```
function showData() { 
//Do something
}

function hideData() {
var delay = 1000;
setTimeout(function(){
//Do something
}, delay);
}
```

And you're good to go. The mouseout event no longer overpowers the click event in Firefox. :) :)